# How do I make the check boxes stay checked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How do I make the checkboxes stay ticked? I want it to save to a local database. Here is where I gave up:

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from sqlite3 import *
import json

box = Tk()

box.geometry('600x450')
box.title('November Assesment Study List')
box.resizable(False,False)

checkbox1 = tk.StringVar()
checkbox2 = tk.StringVar()
checkbox3 = tk.StringVar()

checkboxes = []
sql_as_text = json.dumps(checkboxes)

checkboxes.append(checkbox1)
checkboxes.append(checkbox2)
checkboxes.append(checkbox3)

connection = sqlite3.connect("Checkedboxes.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
# cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Valees (checked integer)")
# query = "INSERT INTO Valees (checked) VALUES (?)"
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Valees (checked) VALUES )")
# cursor.execute(query, [sql_as_text])

r = cursor.fetchall()

def btn1_checked():
    w = checkbox1.get()
    checkboxes.append(w)
    print(str(checkboxes))
    print(r)

def openNewWindow1():
    newWindow = Toplevel(box)
    newWindow.title("Maths")
    newWindow.geometry("400x200")
    ttk.Checkbutton(newWindow, text= 'Algebra', command=btn1_checked, variable=checkbox1, onvalue='1', offvalue='0').pack()
    ttk.Checkbutton(newWindow, text= 'Calculus', onvalue='1', offvalue='0').pack()
    ttk.Checkbutton(newWindow, text= 'Trig', onvalue='1', offvalue='0').pack()

btn = Button(box,
             text ="Maths",
             command = openNewWindow1)
btn.pack(pady = 10)

cursor.close()
connection.commit()
connection.close()
box.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not an **SQLite** question.

Comment: Better use configparser.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a local file. Would be a different approach, but then there is no need to install mysql first.

But you were right. You need to store the state of the checkbox somewhere.

```
checkbox1 = True

f = open("file.txt", "a") # "a" will append to the end of the file.
f.write("checkbox1=" + str(checkbox1) + "\n") # "\n" will create a new paragraph
f.close()

# open read the file
f = open("file.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

Something like this ;)